# How to pass from flash under the external reference?

Tags: javascript, flash, hyperlink, widget, external

I have Mac OS widget with flash. If to click on flash the URL in a window of a browser should open. But it does not occur. I use code like this:

```
DETAILS_HTML='object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="700" height="460" id="start" align="middle">'+
  'param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />'+
  'param name="flashvars" value=SomeParam>'+
  'param name="movie" value=SomeValue />'+
        'param name="wmode" value="transparent" />'+
        'param name="quality" value="best" />'+
  'param name="scale" value="noborder" />'+
        'param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffcc" />'+
  'embed src=SomeSrc quality="best" scale="noborder" bgcolor="#ffffcc" width="700" height="460" name="start" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowScriptAccess="always" wmode="transparent" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars= SomeParam /> /embed>'+
 '/object>';


document.getElementById('flashPlayer').innerHTML=DETAILS_HTML;
```

Please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [swfObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)? You can use the javascript function to replace another container. Look in their wiki [here](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) for what they call "dynamic publishing".

You write:

> window of a browser should open

If you want to open a new browser window, maybe you should use the `window.open` function?
You can find a guide to doing that [here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml).